# Disabling Submit button on form in Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

How can I disable the Submit button on a form after its clicked? The goal is prevent users from hitting the browser's back button and resubmitting the same details twice, as well as clicking it twice in quick succession if the POST method is slower than expected. I found some ideas here which seem to work fine in Safari, but in Chrome it looks like my onSubmit form function doesn't fire as the button's caption doesn't change and the button stays enabled. I need a simple JS/php method for achieving this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<title>Entry Form</title>
<body> 

<h2 align="center">Entry Form - <?php echo date("Y");?></h2>

<form id="entryForm" method="post" action="formSubmit.php" onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">  
 <h3>Entrant Info</h3>
   <div><input name="fName" type="text" size="80" placeholder="Given name(s)" required>  <strong>*</strong></div>
    <br>
    <div><input name="lName" type="text" size="80" placeholder="Last name" required>  <strong>*</strong></div>
    <br>
    <div><input type="tel" name="phone" size="25" pattern="\d{3}[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}" placeholder="Phone number (123-456-7890)"></div>
 <br>
    <div><input type="email" name="email" size="80" placeholder="Email"></div>
    <br>
 <h3>Model Info</h3>
    <div><input type="text" name="modelName" size="80" placeholder="Title or name of entry" required>  <strong>*</strong></div>
    <br>
    <div><textarea name="remarks" rows="10" cols="80" placeholder="Remarks"></textarea></div>
    <br> 

    <select name="category" size="1" required>
    <!--<option value="0">--Please Select --</option>-->
 <option disabled selected value> -- Select a category -- </option>
    <?php

    // Use mySQL Procedurel
    
    // mySQL server connection info
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "xxxx";
    $password = "yyyy";
    $dbname = "zzzz";
    
    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    
    $sql = "SELECT ID, Category FROM category WHERE Year = YEAR(CURDATE()) ORDER BY Category";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Category']; ?></option>
        <?php
        }
    } 
    else {
        echo "No results";
    }
 mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
    </select>  <strong>*</strong>

    <br>
    <br>
    <div>SECURED to base?  
    <input id="securedRadioYes" type="radio" name="securedToBase" value="Yes">Yes
    <input id="securedRadioNo" type="radio" name="securedToBase" value="No" checked>No</div> 
    <div>
    <h4>Terms and Conditions</h4>
    I understand that  the terms.</div>
    <br> 
    <br>
    <div>I accept the Terms and Conditions:
    <input id="acceptAgrmt" name="acceptAgrmt" type="checkbox" value="" required>  <strong>*</strong></div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div>
    <input type="submit" name="mysubmit" value="Submit Entry">
    <input type="button" value="Reset Form" onclick="resetForm(this.form);">
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

  function checkForm(form) // Submit button clicked
  {
    //
    // check form input values
    //

 // User has to check Terms and Conditions
    if(!form.acceptAgrmt.checked) {
  alert("Please indicate that you accept the Terms and Conditions");
  form.acceptAgrmt.focus();
  return false;
    }
 else {
  // do other field validations here?
  form.mysubmit.disabled = true;
  form.mysubmit.value = "Please wait...";
  return true;
 }
  }

  function resetForm(form) // Reset button clicked
  {
    form.mysubmit.disabled = false;
    form.mysubmit.value = "Submit Entry";
 
 // Clear out all user entries
 form.acceptAgrmt.checked=false;
 document.getElementById('securedRadioNo').checked = true;
 form.category.value="";
 form.remarks.value="";
 form.modelName.value="";
 //form.email.value="";
 //form.phone.value="";
 //form.lName.value="";
 //form.fName.value="";
 
  }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also doesn't work in IE11

Answer (score 0):

One way you could deal with this is just to hide or disable `pointer-actions` on the form after it's clicked -- modify the `hidden` attribute of the form element, or set `form.style.pointerActions = "none"`.

Comment: As I'm a noob, could you please be more specific?

Comment: @RossW About what in particular?

Comment: `document.querySelector('entryForm').style.pointerActions = 'none';`

If this helped you, please select the answer as the correct one!